# How to invert relationships using APOC

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I am using `call apoc.refactor.invert(rel)` to invert relationship directions. When I try this on already created graph with relationship type instead of `rel` it gives error

> Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was String/float

and when I try to invert relationships upon creating them with the following query

```
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, graphName.connectionName, {}, b) yield rel1
call apoc.refactor.invert(rel1)
```

it gives error

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown procedure output:
>   `rel1` (line 7, column 67 (offset: 232))  "call
>   apoc.refactor.invert(rel1)

if someone knows the proper use of it please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a relationship type as parameter to `apoc.refactor.invert(rel)` procedure. This procedure accepts a relationship instead.

Your second attempt if falling because `apoc.create.relationship` does not produce a `rel1` output (you can see it running `call apoc.help("apoc.create.relationship")`). This procedure produces `rel` output instead.

So change your code to:

```
call apoc.create.relationship(a, graphName.connectionName, {}, b) yield rel
call apoc.refactor.invert(rel) yield input, output
```